# what does the code mean: if [$? -eq 0] mean?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I'm in the process of generating an automatic installation script. I want to test if the tool already is already installed in the system, I found this line :

```
  if [$? -eq 0]
```

but I did not understand what it means... is it complete or not?

thank you in advance.

Comment: `$?` is the return value of the last executed command.

Comment: It's an error, because you didn't put spaces around the `[` and `]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$?` shows the exit code of the previous process, If everything is ok then the exit code is equals to 0, 1 for the processes having minor problems/warnings and 2 or more than 2 means fatal errors were caused and during termination of the process

so -eq here means equals

so basically this line of code is checking if the exit code of previous process was 0 or not